# Is it possible to generate a keystore file from address and password

Tags: keystore

I think I already know the answer, but thought I would ask anyway. I have lost my keystore file while backing up an ETH wallet. I did not have the private key noted down anywhere else, so currently cannot access my funds. I know the wallet address and the password I used to encrypt the keystore file, so wondered if there is a way to reverse engineer this to generate a new keystore with my private key in there.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - No!

Your password encrypts your private key into the keystore. If you lose the keystore, there is no way to recover your private key. Your address and keystore password are in no way correlated. Sorry about that though.